# Calling function from Window1 to Window2 WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

In my first Window, I created a function where It will load all the data in the database as a dynamic button which is inside the stackpanel,
it is called BindImageList()

```
      public void BindImageList()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT GarmentName,Image FROM tblthesis", conn))
            {
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();


                foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    var imageBuffer = (byte[])dataRow["Image"];
                    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
                    {
                        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                        bitmapImage.EndInit();
                    }

                    KinectTileButton button = new KinectTileButton();

                    button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(7, 7, 7, 7);
                    button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                    button.Width = 185;
                    button.Height = 200;
                    button.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmapImage);
                    button.Click += button_Click;

                    mainWin.spDress.Children.Add(button);

                }
                mainWin.Show();


            }
            conn.Close();



        }

    }


         Window3_loaded 
                {
          BindImagelist();
                 }
```

Which is currently adding buttons in my MainWindow when I insert the code from my Window3_Loaded event but
when I am call that Function from my MainWindow like this:

```
     MainWindow_Loaded{
         Window3 wewe = new Window3();
        wewe.BindImageList();

        }
```

It doesn't create a dynamic button in my stackpanel just like I did when I inserted the code in the loaded event of window3,

but when I make it like this

```
         public void BindImageList()
        {
          messagebox.show(my text);
           }
```

my message box is showing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to just open the window and do this logic in the load event

Comment: The method creates and populates an instance of a main window. So if the method is called twice, you'll end up with two main windows with populated listboxes. There is a lot of code missing in the question so if you want us to help you any better we need a minimal, complete code example.

Comment: Also it's not clear what works and what doesn't. You should rephrase the question.

Comment: I suspect that it's because you are creating a new Window3. How is this window actually displayed? A message box, on the other hand, is always displayed. Can you get a hold of a Window3 that's clearly already displayed and then BindImageList on that instance?

Comment: @wandercoder how to do what you are implementing?

Comment: If you can see Window3 on the screen, then there is a global variable for it somewhere. Use that global instead of creating a new Window3.

Comment: can you show me the answwer? perhaps in code

Comment: I don't have time to generate an application and you haven't posted all of your code in numerous files to use instead. Do a search for Window3 on your entire project. If you can see window3 on your screen, there will likely be an instance of it that has already been created. Use that instance. If this doesn't make sense, or I'm wrong about what the issue is, maybe someone else has an idea.

Comment: Please reformat your code sample(s). It is not just an inconvenience to potential readers, it could have the effect of driving them away. Formatting code matters, and posting badly formatted code sends a signal that the post is not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for Window3 on your entire project. If you can see window3 on your screen, there will likely be an instance of it that has already been created. Use that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you create a new instance of Window3. You need Window1 to call the method of the currently shown instance of Window3. You can do that by two steps:

1. Define a static field of Window3 inside Window3.cs file to hold the current shown instance.

   public static Window3 Current;
   public Window3(){... Current=this;}
2. Use that static field in Window1 to call the method.

   if(Window3.Current!=null)
       Window3.Current.BindImageList();

This way Window1 will call the method on the current active Window3 not on a new instance which is not viewed now.

I hope that helps.